# print a list of numbers on 6 columns python

Tags: python

I have a list or numbers printed like this in one line: 0.232 2.34234 ...1.2232. In total there are 156 numbers. I would like to print only 6 of them in a line like:

```
a b c d e f

g h i j k l
```

...

I have tried this so far, my numbers are in the line.dat:

```
with open('line.dat') as file:
File = file.readlines()
for i in range(len(File)/6+1):
    print ''.join(File[i*6:(i+1)*6])
```

However, this is still printing the numbers in one line. Can anyone help me with this, please! Thanks.

Can I print first 52 numbers in the same column and so on (still 6 columns). I have lots of numbers this time and I want to keep the first 52 and so on numbers in the same column. So in the end I have:

1      53   105   157   209   261

2

...

52    104   156   208   260   312

313   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...

...(another 52 numbers and so on)

Comment: What does `line.dat` look like? Are the numbers all on separate lines?

Comment: the first bit of advice is to get a grip with python's `for` loops and iteration protocol (iterables, iterators, etc). BTW, the indentation is wrong. And you have a typo in the title

Comment: the numbers are listed in one line with one space between them:  0.232   2.342   1.223   3.894...

Comment: Are all the numbers in the form d.ddd, with d a single digit?

Comment: I have d as more digits as well. 99.344, 3450.234...
You are right is not printed in one line, but spread over some more lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `split` the data on whitespace, you cannot slice characters as you will slice off parts of numbers, taking six characters is not the same as taking six of your numbers, unless you knew the exact length of each number substring then you need to separate into individual sub elements with split:

```
with open('line.dat')) as f:
    line = f.read().split()
    print("\n".join([" ".join(line[i:i+6]) for i in xrange(0, len(line)-5, 6)]))
```

Comment: Can I print 52 numbers in a column every time I start a new one, see the above question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools as it

with open('data') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


k = lines[0].split()

i = iter(k)

for j in range(len(k) // 6):
    print(list(it.islice(i, 0, 6)))
```

if file line  is range(156) 
**output**

```
['[0,', '1,', '2,', '3,', '4,', '5,']
['6,', '7,', '8,', '9,', '10,', '11,']
['12,', '13,', '14,', '15,', '16,', '17,']
['18,', '19,', '20,', '21,', '22,', '23,']
['24,', '25,', '26,', '27,', '28,', '29,']
['30,', '31,', '32,', '33,', '34,', '35,']
['36,', '37,', '38,', '39,', '40,', '41,']
['42,', '43,', '44,', '45,', '46,', '47,']
['48,', '49,', '50,', '51,', '52,', '53,']
['54,', '55,', '56,', '57,', '58,', '59,']
['60,', '61,', '62,', '63,', '64,', '65,']
['66,', '67,', '68,', '69,', '70,', '71,']
['72,', '73,', '74,', '75,', '76,', '77,']
['78,', '79,', '80,', '81,', '82,', '83,']
['84,', '85,', '86,', '87,', '88,', '89,']
['90,', '91,', '92,', '93,', '94,', '95,']
['96,', '97,', '98,', '99,', '100,', '101,']
['102,', '103,', '104,', '105,', '106,', '107,']
['108,', '109,', '110,', '111,', '112,', '113,']
['114,', '115,', '116,', '117,', '118,', '119,']
['120,', '121,', '122,', '123,', '124,', '125,']
['126,', '127,', '128,', '129,', '130,', '131,']
['132,', '133,', '134,', '135,', '136,', '137,']
['138,', '139,', '140,', '141,', '142,', '143,']
['144,', '145,', '146,', '147,', '148,', '149,']
['150,', '151,', '152,', '153,', '154,', '155]']
```